# Name of technique behind 3D effects like HTC one dimension plus

Tags: android

The HTC one M8 uses dual cameras to achieve the 3D Dimension plus effect.  What is the name of this technique?

Here's a demonstration:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuKphXzWwII)

Comment: Adding more details, any guidance on how to achieve this? or what effects are combined in this ?

Comment: This question is not _really_ a programming question. Having said that, there is a good, programming related answer, so I wouldn't vote to close. Can the question be improved?

Comment: Extracting the library jar from https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-dual-lens-api/htc-dual-lens-sdk-installation/   and decompiling using jad exposes readable java files and unfortunate .so files Its not know what this effect is called

Comment: @YvetteColomb, When first looking at this question, my issue was that the question, as phrased, reads more like a general question rather than a question specific to programming. There's a line in there somewhere, it felt like, and still feels like, this question was/is on the non-programming side of it. Maybe I'm just interpreting it wrong, but it sounds more like a HTC-fan-person just asking for the name of something they find cool, not someone asking for more information with the intent of programming something. Perhaps all it needs is a good edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's image processing using a depth map, for more information see:
https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-dual-lens-api

No need to reverse engineer - the DimensionPlus effect is simply an implementation of the 2D-plus effect (if you need a name) as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D-plus-depth

This effect uses the depth map included in the photos to create a standard geometry which the SDK uses to visualize the effect using gyro (alternatively you can program touch navigation).

Answer (score 1):

The 3D Dimension Plus effect is achieved using the Dual Lens SDK provided by HTC here:

https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/htc-dual-lens-api/htc-dual-lens-sdk-installation/

If you download the SDK, it will include samples that show you how to achieve the desired effect.

Here is a sample of the code found in the SDK Samples, courtesy of HTC:

```
public class DimenstionPlusActivity extends Activity {
    private DimensionPlusView dimensionPlusView;

    final String filename = "dimensionPlusSample.jpg"; // copy to root of sdcard

    private File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final String filepath = root+"/"+filename;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dimensionPlusView = (DimensionPlusView) findViewById(R.id.dimensionPlusView);
        try {
            dimensionPlusView.loadDimensionPlusFile(filepath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(e.getMessage().contains("READFILE_ERROR")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),filename+" not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),filename+" not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dimensionPlusView.onResume();
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(mSenserEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        dimensionPlusView.onPause();
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(mSenserEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        dimensionPlusView.release();
    }

    private SensorEventListener mSenserEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // gyro event
            float gravity1 = event.values[0];
            float gravity2 = event.values[1];

            int orientation = ((WindowManager) DimenstionPlusActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            switch (orientation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                dimensionPlusView.gyro(-gravity2, gravity1);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                dimensionPlusView.gyro(-gravity1, -gravity2);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                dimensionPlusView.gyro(gravity2, -gravity1);
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                dimensionPlusView.gyro(gravity1, gravity2);
                break;
            default:
                dimensionPlusView.gyro(-gravity2, gravity1);
                break;
            }

            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what effects are inside DimensionPlusView

Comment: There aren't really any "effects". DimensionPlusView is a feature that gives images a 3D effect. That done using the `gyro` method. If you download the SDK, it contains the docs, and you will see what I mean. If you are looking to create effects, you will want the `DualLens` Class.

Comment: Yes exactly. Its mostly done in the MatrixJNILib.java (got these by reverse engineering) Most of the methods are implemented in native, so its unclear.